# MVC 3 Registration Confirmation Email

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, email-confirmation

I'm using the stock MembershipProvider but I would like to add a method to send a confirmation email to the use upon registration. Without doing it directly within my Register actionresult, what would be the best way to do it?

I'm quite new to MVC so please take that in consideration in your reply.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would strongly recommend you [MvcMailer](https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer/wiki/MvcMailer-Step-by-Step-Guide) for email sending from an ASP.NET MVC application. [Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/) also [blogged about it](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeek2MvcMailerSendsMailsWithASPNETMVCRazorViewsAndScaffolding.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest submitting the request to send the confirmation email into some queue and letting a background process to send all emails.

Answer (score 3):

[Postal](http://aboutcode.net/postal/) FTW.

*Nuget* it, add a view for the email, add a few lines of Postal code, all done.

Simple and easy, which is the complete opposite of using the regular .NET mail stuff.